# Using .get to integrate a function

Tags: python, tkinter, integration

I am using tkinter and scipy to make a program that integrates a function, lets say with respect to x. this is my code:

```
def newtest1():
intwindow = Tk()

Label(intwindow, text = 'enter here', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=0)
Label(intwindow, text = 'enter upper bound', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=1)
Label(intwindow, text = 'enter lower bound', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=2)

get1 = IntVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = get1).grid(row=0, column=1)

getupper = IntVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = getupper).grid(row=1, column=1)

getlower = IntVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = getlower).grid(row=2, column=1)

bty = Button(intwindow, text='click', command = lambda: newfunction()).grid(row=3)

def newfunction():
    x69 = get1.get()
    x_upper = getupper.get()
    x_lower = getlower.get()

    testz = int(x69)
    upperz= int(x_upper)
    lowerz = int(x_lower)



    x9 = lambda x: x69
    res = integrate.quad(x9, x_lower,x_upper)        

    randomwindow = Tk()
    label = Label(randomwindow, text = 'you got {} '.format(round(res[0])))
    label.grid(row=1)

   # Label(randomwindow, text = 'you got %s ' % res).grid(row=1)
    randomwindow.mainloop()



mainloop()
newtest1()
```

if you look inside the function newfunction() there is the code

```
    x9 = lambda x: x69
    res = integrate.quad(x9, x_lower,x_upper)
```

I was hoping that in the pop up box, I could enter something like say 2*x and it would integrate. However previously I used get1 = IntVar() when testing to see if numbers work in the entry box. I tried removing this for what Im currently trying to achieve but that gives some logical errors. Why can't I enter my own function in terms of x in the pop up box so that python can integrate it?

EDIT

---

@furas this is the code i use now

```
import numpy
from numpy import *
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
from tkinter import *



def newtest1():
intwindow = Tk()

Label(intwindow, text = 'enter here', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=0)
Label(intwindow, text = 'enter upper bound', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=1)
Label(intwindow, text = 'enter lower bound', font = ('Symbol')).grid(row=2)

get1 = StringVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = get1).grid(row=0, column=1)

getupper = IntVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = getupper).grid(row=1, column=1)

getlower = IntVar()
Entry(intwindow, textvariable = getlower).grid(row=2, column=1)

bty = Button(intwindow, text='click', command = lambda: newfunction()).grid(row=3)

def newfunction():
    x69 = get1.get()
    x_upper = getupper.get()
    x_lower = getlower.get()

    #testz = int(x69)
    upperz= int(x_upper)
    lowerz = int(x_lower)



    x9 = eval(f"lambda x: {x69}")
    res = integrate.quad(x9, x_lower,x_upper)        

    randomwindow = Tk()
    label = Label(randomwindow, text = 'you got {} '.format(round(res[0])))
    label.grid(row=1)

   # Label(randomwindow, text = 'you got %s ' % res).grid(row=1)
    randomwindow.mainloop()



mainloop()
newtest1()
```

And this is the error i get

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/isa/Desktop/Diff Eqns/diffeqn.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    bty = Button(intwindow, text='click', command = lambda: newfunction()).grid(row=3)
  File "/Users/isa/Desktop/Diff Eqns/diffeqn.py", line 58, in newfunction
    x9 = eval(lambda x: {x69})
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. if you get error then show it in question (not comment) as text (not image)

Comment: and create correctly formatted code (with all import) so we could run it and see problem.

Comment: if you want to put string `"2*x"` in box then you would have to use `StringVar()` instead of `IntVar()` to get it. And probably `x9 = eval(f"lambad x: {x69}")` to convert string `"2*x"` to code `x9 = lambda x: 2*x`

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Comment: @furas please see my edit for the error i get when i use x9 = eval(f"lambad x: {x69}")

Comment: eval need string and I used even f-string to put content of `x69` into this string. `f"lambad x: {x69}"` - and your erro shows that you didn't use string `x9 = eval(lambda x: {x69})`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put string `"2*x"` in `Entry` then you would have to use `StringVar()` instead of `IntVar()` to get it.

And you need to use `eval()` to convert this string to function which can calculate value

```
x9 = lambda x: eval(x69)
```

or with f-string or `.format()` to put this string inside other string

```
x9 = eval(f"lambad x: {x69}")
x9 = eval("lambad x: {}".format(x69)")
```

In code below I used names which means something so it looks lik

```
function = lambda x: eval(function_str)
```

---

In code I add also other changes - mostly related to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---

def newtest1():

    # - subfunctions -

    def on_button_click(): # PEP8: name of function should means something
        function_str = function_var.get() # PEP8: name of variable should means something
        upper_int = upper_var.get()
        lower_int = lower_var.get()

        function = lambda x: eval(function_str)
        #function = eval(f"lambda x: {function_str}")
        result = integrate.quad(function, lower_int, upper_int)        
        result = round(result[0])

        randomwindow = tk.Toplevel() # second windows should use `Toplevel()` without `mainloop
        label = tk.Label(randomwindow, text=' you got {} '.format(result))
        label.grid(row=1)

        #tk.Label(randomwindow, text=' you got %s ' % result).grid(row=1)

    # - main -

    intwindow = tk.Tk()

    options = {'font': 'Symbol'}
    tk.Label(intwindow, text='enter here', **options).grid(row=0)  # PEP8: without spaces around '='
    tk.Label(intwindow, text='enter upper bound', **options).grid(row=1)
    tk.Label(intwindow, text='enter lower bound', **options).grid(row=2)

    function_var = tk.StringVar() # PEP8: name of variable should means something
    tk.Entry(intwindow, textvariable=function_var).grid(row=0, column=1)

    upper_var = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Entry(intwindow, textvariable=upper_var).grid(row=1, column=1)

    lower_var = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Entry(intwindow, textvariable=lower_var).grid(row=2, column=1)

    tk.Button(intwindow, text='click', command=on_button_click).grid(row=3) # you don't need `lambda` when function created at start

    intwindow.mainloop()

# --- main ---

newtest1()
```

Comment: How come if I enter something like sin(x) into the box it cannot integrate it?

Comment: you have `sin()`/`cos()`/etc. in module `math` so you would need to do `from math import *` at start - and then you can use `eval("sin(x)")`. But this `sin()`/`cos()`/etc. needs radians so if you want to work with angles then maybe better use `import math` and create function `def sin(angle): return math.sin(math.radians(angle))`